# Sort Items Based on Item Order and Parent Category Order using MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two Tables "Table1" is master Category and "Table2" is Items both tables have items in particular order

In Table1 Categories are ordered by CatOrder in ASC and in Table2 Items are also ordered in ItemOrder.

Now i need to display Items based on order of CatOrder and then "ItemOrder

```
Table1
CatID
CatName
CatType
CatOrder

Table2
ItemID
ItemName
ItemLogo
ItemDetails
CatType
ItemOrder
```

How can i sql query so that it will get first all items based on CatOrder & then ItemOrder

```
Select ItemName, ItemOrder FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t1 ON T1.CatType = T2.CatType Order By T2.CatOrder
```

Above Query doesnt get intended result & when i add Group By It get aggregate function error

Expected Result

```
Item    |CatOrder   |   ItemOrder
Item 1  |   10  |   10
Item 3  |   10  |   20
Item 2  |   10  |   30
Item 5  |   20  |   10
Item 4  |   20  |   20
Item 6  |   20  |   30
Item 7  |   30  |   10
```

Comment: Why are you joining the two tables when you have all the required columns in Table2, and what is the expected output after you add group by

Comment: I have to display Data based on category Order also which is in Table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use multiple `order by`

the order sort will depend on your `order by` columns order.

```
Select ItemName, CatOrder,ItemOrder
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.CatType = T2.CatType
Order By CatOrder,ItemOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to get the desired result -

```
Select ItemName, CatOrder, ItemOrder 
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON T1.CatType = T2.CatType 
Order By T1.CatOrder, t2.ItemOrder
```